# How to check shipping availability based on zip code in magento

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, magento-1.8

I have searched more about how to develop a simple zip code validation in `magento` that allow users to check shipping availability based on their zip code.

I need to import zip code in magento that should be stored in the database, when the user enter zip code for checking shipping availability, `magento` should check whether that zip code is available in database. If it's available the output should be `shipping available` otherwise `shipping not available`.

Answer (score 0):

So you will need to validate the ZIP code against a list of valid or available codes.

I would add an extra validation functions to the shipping/billing actions on the OneController.

See:
http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/validate-your-input-magento-style/